# how to avoid white space between sections

Tags: spacing

I have section 1 which is only half a page and section 2 following it. However, 2 started in a new page instead of starting in the bottom half of the previous page. As a result i have section 1 in the top half the page and the bottom page is blank creating a large white space. I need to move section 2 to the previous page.

The code is:

\section{section 1} 
    ........
    .......
   \section{section 2} 
    ......

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{placeins}

\begin{document}



\FloatBarrier\section{Thesis Statement}
his research is intended to explore methods for providing ....
\textbf{Thesis statement}: A framework can be leveraged to improve the channel
performance in a dynamic environment at various types of obstructing objects,
for high frequency mobile network technologies.

\begin{table}[b]
  \centering
  TTT
  \caption{zzz}
\end{table}

\FloatBarrier\section{Anticipated Research Contributions}
This dissertation is guided by the desire to perform the following:
\begin{itemize}
\item ........ 
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: latex presumably decided the section did not fit on the page, perhaps the first paragraph of that section is a big unbreakable unit such as a table, and headings always stay with their first paragraph. Since you have not shown any code it is impossible to guess why the page breaks are as they are, or suggest how to change code that you have not shown.

Comment: \FloatBarrier\section{Thesis Statement}
  This research is intended to explore methods for providing ....
  \textbf{Thesis statement}: A framework can be leveraged to improve the channel performance in a dynamic environment at various types of obstructing objects, for high frequency mobile network technologies.
\FloatBarrier\section{Anticipated Research Contributions} 

        This dissertation is guided by the desire to perform the following:
        \begin{itemize}
        \item ........

 \end{itemize}

Comment: Please include your code in your original post by editing it!

Comment: @ray please make it a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) also I don't know the `\FloatBarrier` commands: are they specific to some class you use?

Comment: @ray -- Surely you can see that a document which contained only(!) `\section{section 1} ........ ....... \section{section 2} ......` will not cause the problem you describe. For LaTeX documents, tiny snippets of code are almost always of no value whatsoever. A good question usually --- and this certainly applies here --- is a **minimal but complete `.tex` file that demonstrates the problem**. In effect, this means starting with `\documentclass` and going to `\end{document}`, but skipping out all the packages and document text that are not needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: For example, your comment suggests you are using `\FloatBarrier`, but not everyone knows that comes from the `placeins` package....

Comment: This is a thesis with multiple chapters and each chapter is in different file. Not sure what to post. Basically what I need is to get rid of white space between sections and make the following sections starts in he same pape as the previous section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\FloatBarrier` flushes any pending floats at that point by issuing a `\clearpage` which forces the following section head on to a new page. If you want the section headings to always start on the current page then you should not use `\FloatBarrier`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{placeins}

\begin{document}



\FloatBarrier\section{Thesis Statement}
his research is intended to explore methods for providing ....
\textbf{Thesis statement}: A framework can be leveraged to improve the channel
performance in a dynamic environment at various types of obstructing objects,
for high frequency mobile network technologies.

\begin{table}[b]
  \centering
  TTT
  \caption{zzz}
\end{table}

%\FloatBarrier
\section{Anticipated Research Contributions}
This dissertation is guided by the desire to perform the following:
\begin{itemize}
\item ........ 
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```